# Why do I get SIGSEGV?

Tags: c++

I just started learning c++ and encountered some weird behavior, the results of the below code is:

```
0x7ffee729ba58

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Code:

```
int i  = 23;
int &ref_i = i;
cout << &i << endl;

int *p;
cout << *p << endl;
```

But if I remove the second line `int &ref_i = i;`, the reuslt is as expected:

```
0x7ffee262ca58

0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why? Thanks!

Comment: `p` isn't Initialized, so using it invokes UB. And deference a pointer to nowhere also invokes UB

Comment: I am new to c++, but I feel like it is a kind of undefined behavior.  You get random garbage.  Don't try to identify the reason, because it is all garbaged.

Comment: Thank you, all! Your comments cleared my doubt.

Comment: What you see is that C++ will not initialize any of your variables for you until you tell C++ to do so. In this case *p is a pointer pointing to an int (address of int) but it has not been initialized and my not anywhere valid. Where it points is random and your program may give different "results" each time you run it. (This is what is refered to by undefined behavior)

Comment: The code provided does not compile.

Comment: @Elijay :: it compiles :: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/811f65efebd4f673

Comment: It compiles only after adding `include` directives, a `using` statement, and placing the code inside a function.